# Loop logic help needed - Can't compare correctly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I have the following table:

[image: The table]

And I use this function to get data from it:

```
function get_cart_by($player_id)
{
    global $db;

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) FROM ' . PCP_MARKET_CART . ' 
        WHERE player_id = ' . (int) $player_id;
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $rowset = $db->sql_fetchrowseT($result);
    $db->sql_freeresult($result);

    $cart = array();
    foreach ($rowset as $item)
    {
        $cart[] = $item['item_id']; 
    }

    return $cart;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 49
    [3] => 48
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 51
)
```

Now I have an array that lists all my products from another table without looking at the `player_id`. I want to use the array demonstrated above and add a custom class to the items that do not use the `player_id`, like show which items the user already has on cart.

The other array that lists all the products looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 16
            [parent_id] => 11
            [cat_position] => 0
            [item_position] => 1
            [item_type] => product
            [item_title] => Custom Business
            [item_description] => Some description
            [item_price] => 9.99
            [item_units] => 500
            [item_preview] => http://i.imgur.com/3eCpMMm.png
            [times_sold] => 0
            [daopay_url] => http://i.imgur.com/QA7bBfJ.jpg
            [public] => 1
            [time] => 1384709635
        )

       [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 17
            [parent_id] => 11
            [cat_position] => 0
            [item_position] => 1
            [item_type] => product
            [item_title] => Custom Business
            [item_description] => Some description
            [item_price] => 9.99
            [item_units] => 500
            [item_preview] => http://i.imgur.com/3eCpMMm.png
            [times_sold] => 0
            [daopay_url] => http://i.imgur.com/QA7bBfJ.jpg
            [public] => 1
            [time] => 1384709635
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 49
            [parent_id] => 11
            [cat_position] => 0
            [item_position] => 1
            [item_type] => product
            [item_title] => Custom Business
            [item_description] => Some description
            [item_price] => 9.99
            [item_units] => 500
            [item_preview] => http://i.imgur.com/3eCpMMm.png
            [times_sold] => 0
            [daopay_url] => http://i.imgur.com/QA7bBfJ.jpg
            [public] => 1
            [time] => 1384709635
        )


)
```

Now based on the first array, I want to mark the same item IDs on the second arrays and show that they are different (on cart).

I have tried quite a lot and for some reason, I managed to mark only item_id 16 and 17, the rest are not getting "marked" for some reason.

This is the code I used:

```
$cartar = $market->get_cart_by($user->data['player_id']);
$cartln = sizeof($cartar) - 1;

// Fetch items of the selected category
    $items = $market->fetch_cat_items($cat_id); // Equivalent to the array above    
    $index  = 0;

    print_r($items);

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $name = $item['item_name'];
                if ($cartln >= $index)
        {
            if ($cartar[$index] == $item['item_id'])
                $name .= $cartar[$index];
        }

        echo $name;

                $index++;
    }
```

I tried to make the example explain my case the best way possible. So, when I echo out `$name` it only outputs `thename16` and `thename17` (those two), but it doesn't continue to 49 and so on.

Please be aware that the array with all the products in it is quite large, I made it shorter for demonstration purposes only.

Were am I failing in my code? Why are only the first two items getting "marked"? I'm quite in a hurry right now, once I get back from a meeting I'll try to explain my issue further.

Comment: whats the sense of `if ($cartln >= $index)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know if i understood correctly but maybe you want to do it like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $name = $item['item_name'];

    if(in_array($item['item_id'],$cartar)) {
            $name .= $item['item_id'];
    }
    echo $name;
}
```

used `in_array()` to check if the item_id exists somewhere in `$cartar`. No matter on which position in array.